# How to replace from the nth occurence to nth occurrence of a very long string using sed

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I have a very long string, with over 2000 occurrences, and it look like that:

### Input:

### 1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8absoad8ryaa90thneas... and more than

I want replace mutiple occurrences at the 3rd to the 450th occurrence in string to output:

### 1a2a3A4A5A6A7A8AbsoAd8ryAA90thneAs... and more than

I replaced "a" to "A", it replaced from the 3rd occurrence to ending, but I only want to replace from 3rd to 450th, this is my old script:

```
echo "1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8absoad8ryaa90thneas..." | sed 's/a/A/3g';
```

Does anyone help me? Or is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: Show how much you have tried till now.!!

Comment: Many times. Use "awk" or "sed"? Is there no way, sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose a character that you know for sure is not present in your input.. for example the ASCII NUL character, then you could do

```
$ # replacing 3rd to 4th
$ echo "a1a23a5a62a34a235a" | sed 's/a/\x0/3g; s/\x0/a/3g; s/\x0/A/g'
a1a23A5A62a34a235a
$ # replacing 3rd to 5th
$ echo "a1a23a5a62a34a235a" | sed 's/a/\x0/3g; s/\x0/a/4g; s/\x0/A/g'
a1a23A5A62A34a235a
$ # replacing 3rd to 6th
$ echo "a1a23a5a62a34a235a" | sed 's/a/\x0/3g; s/\x0/a/5g; s/\x0/A/g'
a1a23A5A62A34A235a
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the string to a variable and then use brace expansion to target the positional character in the string you want to replace using bash global replace. Consider the following example:

```
## Our sample string. ##
string="abcde01234

## New, changed string. ##
echo "${string//${string:0:1}/${string:5:1}}"
```

In this example, when run as a bash script, the first character of `$string` is replaced with the sixth character of `$string`. Knowing this little trick, I am sure you will figure out a way to do what you need without having to use `sed`. Or, you can use the brace expansion similarly in `sed`.

```
## Our sample string ##
string="abcde01234"

## New, changed, string. Output is the same as above example. ##
sed -e "s/${string:0:1}/${string:5:1}/g" <(echo "$string")
```

This should be enough to get you headed in the right direction as far as figuring out the best way for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/a/\n&/3;s//&\n/450;h;y/a/A/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file
```

Split the string up into pieces using a marker (newline cannot occur in an unadulterated string because it is how sed splits up files), make a copy and then make changes, append the copy and rearrange the pieces.

Alternatively use GNU sed global replace flag:

```
sed 's/a/\n/451g;s//A/3g;s/\n/a/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. I think so too.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -E ':again ; s/^(.{4,449})a/\1A/ ; t again' file`

you can use `t` command to [branch to label](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Branching-and-flow-control.html). This is a conditional *go to* `:label` when a replacement has happened. So for a character range `[x:y]`, regexp `.*{x-1,y-1}a` will match greedy for first time, but we loop until there are no more matches.